# \polylongdiv with multiple variables

Tags: polynom

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and wanted to to do a polynomial division with 3 variables.
So I found the `polynom` package and tried:

```
\polyset{style=C, div=:,vars=x}
\polylongdiv{49a^2 - 9b^2 - 30bx - 25x^2}{7a + 3b + 5x}
```

But it goes on and on without compiling and the pdflatex process runs at 100%.

Is there another command? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: tenacious, would you mind posting a mock-up picture (done with some other tool) that shows what this expression should look like when compiled?

Comment: Looks like it's getting stuck in a loop. May be beyond the capacities of the package. Your example is a bit trickier than those given in the package docs, in which the divisor is something like `x+1`

Comment: From the package documentation: "Multivariate polynomials are currently not supported."  Even `\polyadd\A{x + a}{x + b}` does not work.  I think the package is mostly meant to be used with integer coefficients.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for a feature that the package says to be unavailable